# Editor buttons not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part, html-form-web-part

I am setting up a SharePoint environment and have encountered an issue.

I'm trying to set up a simple form using web parts/html-form editor. However, when I try edit the form content, the "Source edit"-button is not working (i.e. nothing happens when clicking it). Also seen in added picture - the environment is unfortunately in Swedish.

I have also tried installing Form7, but encountered a similar problem; when trying to configure web part/content editor, the URL-button is "dead" - shown in second picture.

Any idea whats going on? Popup-windows are enabled.

[image: Form content edit]

[image: URL-button]

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried on a different one?

Comment: Problem solved, I used Chrome when not working but when trying in IE it worked!

Comment: Never occured to me that a slow beast like IE would be better than Chrome at anything.

Comment: Sometimes it surprises you!